# soapenv:Client, faultstring: Template Parameters inconsistent with request parameters

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

soapenv:Client, faultstring: Template Parameters inconsistent with request parameters.
I am getting this error while calling soap client function
XML Request
this is may XML request

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:abs="http://xx.yz.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <abs:Notification>
     <ClientId>xxxxx</ClientId>
     <ClientAuthorization>xxxx</ClientAuthorization>
     <TemplateId>xxxxx</TemplateId>
     <Recipients>
        <Recipient>
           <NationalOrIqamaId>xxxxxx</NationalOrIqamaId>
           <Language>xxxx</Language>
           <Params>
              <Param>
                 <Name>xxxxx</Name>
                 <Value>xxxx</Value>
              </Param>
              <Param>
                 <Name>xxxx</Name>
                 <Value>xxxxx</Value>
              </Param>
              <Param>
                 <Name>xxxxx</Name>
                 <Value>xxxxx</Value>
              </Param>
           </Params>
        </Recipient>
         </Recipients>
       </abs:Notification>
      </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

while my php soap client request.
Params are optional if i give than i got the error
VAR01 required element missing

```
    $wsdl           = 'xxxxx?wsdl';
    $endpoint       = 'xxxx';
     $certificate    = 'xxxxxx.pem';
     $password       = 'xxxx';

    $options = array(
    'location'      => $endpoint,
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'local_cert'    => $certificate,
      'passphrase'    => $password,
     'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,

       );
      $params = new stdClass();
      $params->ClientId = xxxxxx;
      $params->ClientAuthorization="xxxxxxx";
      $params->TemplateId="xxxxx";
      $params->Recipients=array(
      "Recipient"=>array(
      "NationalOrIqamaId"=>xxxx,
       "Language"=>"xxxxx",
 
         )



     );
      try{
         var_dump($soapClient ->SubmitRequest($params));

       } catch(SoapFault $fault) {
          trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: 
      {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
       }
```